# How to close Kendoui Popup window manually

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using `kendo-ui` controls with `asp.net MVC`. I have two different views.

```
edituser.cshtml
changepasssword.cshtml
```

When user click on change password button from edituser page it popup the ChangePassword page. this page has its own save button. I want to close the popup on save button after changing the password.

**Code for EditUser.cshtml :**

```
<div id="winUserInfo" style="display: none; overflow: hidden;"></div>

  var winUserInfo = $('#winUserInfo');

if (!winUserInfo.data('kendoWindow')) {
    winUserInfo.kendoWindow({
        width: 400,
        height: 140,
        title: 'Change Password',
        modal: true,
        iframe: true
    })
    }


   $('#btnChangePwd').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var w = winUserInfo.data('kendoWindow');

    w.refresh({
        url: '/tools/ChangePassword/?loginID=@(Model.LoginID)'
    }).open().center();
});
```

**Code for ChangePassword.cshtml :**

```
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
<table class="data-form">

    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><label>New Password</label></td>
        <td><input id="txtPassword1" class="required" type="password" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: right;"><label>Re-type New Password</label></td>
        <td><input id="txtPassword2" class="required" type="password" style="width: 200px;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div style="padding-top: 15px;">
    @*<button id="btnClose" class="k-button" onclick="javascript:window.close();">Close</button>*@
    <button id="btnSaveCP" class="k-button"">Save</button>
    <span id="loader"></span>
    <label id="lblMessage" style="display: none; color: green;"></label>
</div>
```

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnSaveCP').click(function () {
    var d = JSON.stringify({
        password1: $('#txtPassword1').val(),
        password2: $('#txtPassword2').val(),
        loginID: '@(ViewBag.LoginID)'
    });

    nf.control.disable($('.k-button'));
    nf.progress.start($('#loader'));

    $('#lblMessage').hide();

    nf.ajax(
        "/Users/ChangePassword",
        d,
        function (e) {
            nf.control.enable($(".k-button"));
            nf.progress.stop($('#loader'));

            if (e.HasError) {
                nf.msgBox.error(e.ErrorMessage);
                return;
            }

            $('#lblMessage').html('Password has been changed').show();
            $('#txtPassword1').val('');
            $('#txtPassword2').val('');

        },
        function (e) {
            nf.control.enable($(".k-button"));
            nf.progress.stop($('#loader'));
            nf.msgBox.ajaxError(e);
        }
    );
});

$(function () {
    $('#txtPassword1').focus();
});
```

I want to close the popup window on click of save button which is in the the popup window(changepassword.cshtml)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i did to resolve the issue. I set iframe = false and made i called the close click of popup by jquery as below.

> $('span.k-i-close').click();

It works for me.

Comment: @Jefftopia your solution doesn't work for me. I have tried everything. Nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Write following on Save button click when you want to close the popup:

```
$("#winUserInfo").data("kendoWindow").close();
```

Comment: What's the error? Is $("#winUserInfo") available in $('#btnSaveCP').click() method?

Comment: Now I have set iframe = false and then i have triggered the click on cross button of popup window with jquery.

Comment: You should log the error. @SBirthare is suggesting the correct method. If 'close()' does not work, you have another problem in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `close()` method to force the kendo window instance to close.

By the way, you should either defined the action inside an observable and bind it to the view, or bind the functionality inside the Kendo Window instance, see [custom action bindings](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/window/overview#custom-actions).

Example:

```
var localView: kendo.View = new kendo.View(

    'foo',

    {   

        // Your function is data; bind it to the view
        // you could change your template s.t. 
        //    a clickable has data-bind="click: mySaveFunction"

        model: { mySaveFunction: mySaveFunction },

        evalTemplate: true,

        init: function() {

        // another way: inject the custom save logic into 
        // the kendo window when it is constructed

            $("<div />").append(localView.render())
                .appendTo("body")
                .kendoWindow({
                    actions: ["customSave"]
                    modal : true,
                    pinned: true,
                    resizable : false,                                                                   
                    title : "Confirm Delete",
                    width: 500
                }).data("kendoWindow").wrapper.find("#custom-save")
                    .click(function(e) {

                        //save logic

                        alert("Saved");

                        this.close();

                    }).center().open();

            }

    });
```

Comment: If the `close()` method does not work, you have other issues with your approach.